# Is there a relation between $l_p$-norms of functions with same Fourier spectra but w.r.t different measures on the Hamming cube?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-analysis

Informally, I want to ask if two functions $f$ and $g$ on the Hamming cube have the same Fourier spectra but w.r.t different measure and basis, then is $||f||_p$ related to $||g||_p$? (Where each $p$-norm is measured according to the appropriate measure.) This question requires some notation to set up more precisely.

First, for the Hamming cube $\{0,1 \}^d$,  given a bias parameter $0 \leq b \leq 1$, we may construct a biased measure $\mu_b$ that assigns a weight $b$ to $1$ bits and $1-b$ to $0$ bits as follows:

\begin{equation}
\mu_b(x) = b^{\sum_i x_i} (1-b)^{d - \sum_i x_i}.
\end{equation}

We continue that expectations and $l_p$-norms can also be defined under this measure. So for example, $ E_b[f] = \sum_{x \in \{0,1\}^d} \mu_b(x) f(x)$ and $||f||_p = 
\left( \sum_{x \in \{0,1 \}^d} \mu_b(x) (f(x))^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} $. We note now an Fourier parity basis for the space $F_b$ of all functions $f: \{0,1\}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ when $\{0,1\}^d$ is associated with measure $\mu_b$. First for each $x \in \{0,1\}^d$ and $i \in [d]$ we define:
 \begin{equation}\chi_i^b =  \begin{cases} 
      \sqrt{\frac{b}{1-b}} & x_i = 0 \\
      -\sqrt{\frac{1-b}{b}} & x_i = 1 \\
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}

This set of $\chi_i^b$ essentially correspond to a bit wise parity basis, which we can extent to arbitrary $S \subset [d]$ as 
$\chi_S^b(x) = \prod_{i \in S} \chi_i^b(x)$. The collection $\{\chi_S^b \}$ over all $S \subset [d]$ is now our desired orthonormal basis of size $2^d$. All this notation reduces to the standard Fourier basis and notions for $b = \frac{1}{2}$.

Now after all that lengthy build-in, here is my question. Suppose $f$ is a function over $\{0,1 \}^d$ with measure $\mu_{1/2}$ and $g$ is a function over $\{0,1 \}^d$ with measure $\mu_b$ (for $b \neq \frac{1}{2}$) and suppose $f$ and $g$ **have the same Fourier cofficients** w.r.t their corresponding bases elements $\chi_S^{1/2}$ and $\chi_S^b$ . Parseval's immediately implies $||f||_2 = ||g||_2$, where each norm is calculated according to the measure of the space the function lies in ($\mu_{1/2}$ and $\mu_b$ respectively). Is this true for all the $l_p$ norms on the Hamming cube? And if not, as I believe to be the case, is there at least some general relation between $||f||_p$  and $||g||_p$?

(Note:This question is crossposted from CS theory stackexchange , where there has been no answer for two weeks.)

Comment: [Link to TCS version](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/20161). Also, I think in "$\mu_b$ assigns a weight $b$ to $0$ bits and $1−b$ to $1$ bits" you have 0 and 1 switched around. (Looking at the definition of $\mu_b$ that immediately follows.)

Comment: Also, you sometimes write $[n]$ instead of $[d]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, $l_p$ norms need not the same for $p\ne 2$. Take $d=1$, $f=\chi^{1/2}_1$ and $g=\chi^b_1$: then $\|f\|_p=1$ for all $p$, but for $b\ne 1/2$,
$$\|g\|_p=\left(\left(\frac{b}{1-b}\right)^{p/2}(1-b)+\left(\frac{1-b}{b}\right)^{p/2}b\right)^{1/p} \tag{1}$$
which is a strictly increasing function of $p$. As $p\to\infty$, (1) grows to 
$$\left(\max\left(\frac{b}{1-b},\frac{1-b}{b}\right)\right)^{1/2} $$

On the other hand, for $f=g\equiv 1$ we have  $\|f\|_p=\|g\|_p=1$ for all $p$. This shows that there is no direct relation (in the form of an identity) between the $l_p$ norms in two different measures.

One can write down some inequalities, of course. The crudest one is obtained just by using the fact that $\|f\|_2=\|g\|_2$ and 
the general relation between $\ell_p$ norms on purely atomic probability spaces. Namely, if $\delta$ is the smallest measure of an atom, then $p\mapsto \delta^{-1/p}\|f\|_p$ is a decreasing function of $p$, while $\|f\|_p$ is an increasing function of $p$. For unbiased measure we have $\delta=2^{-d}$, hence
$$ 2^{d/2-d/p}\le   \|f\|_p \le 1,\quad 1\le p\le 2 $$ 
$$ 1 \le   \|f\|_p \le 2^{d/2-d/p},\quad 2\le p\le \infty $$ 
For the biased measure (i.e., for $g$) similar estimates hold with $2$ replaced by  $1/\min(b,1-b)$. This allows you to compare $\|f\|_p$ and $\|g\|_p$ by chaining the inequalities above. As I said, this is crude in the sense that the  information about coefficients  is used only through Parseval.

You can certainly do better, but I'm afraid you can't do *spectacularly* better than that. Take $f=\chi^{1/2}_S$ and $g=\chi^b_S$ where $S=[d]$. The maximum of $g$ is 
$$\left(\max\left(\frac{b}{1-b},\frac{1-b}{b}\right)\right)^{d/2} \tag{2}$$
which is pretty big compared to $1$. And when $p$ is large, the $l_p$ norm of $g$ approaches (2).